# Android carousel, image perspective transformation

Tags: java, android, matrix, imageview, transform

Could you help me how can I make Android view with images as on the screenshot:

[image]

It must fit screen width.
I can transform the first image, from left, like:

```
    ImageView img;
    float degrees = 70;
    Camera mCamera = new Camera();
    final float mCenterX = img.getWidth() / 2.0f;
    final float mCenterY = img.getHeight() / 2.0f;

    final float centerX = mCenterX;
    final float centerY = mCenterY;
    final Camera camera = mCamera;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    camera.save();

    camera.rotateY(degrees);

    camera.getMatrix(matrix);
    camera.restore();

    matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
    matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
    img.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

In the layout imageViews are stored inside Horizontal LinearLayout. But image width isn't recalculated with matrix transformation.

Please, help me to implement this layout, as on the picture.

Comment: it is easier to use `Matrix#setPolyToPoly`